# Find & Concatenate characters that appear more than once

Tags: vba, excel

I just looked at the possible answers here but could not find one. My question is that i want to find characters that appear more then once in a word/phrase.

**For Example:**

if i input Faseehh result should be `e,h`
if i input Fawwd result should be `w`
if i input Faroq result should be `-`

I developed follwing code but this is giving me value error.

```
Function CountRept(textt As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim temp As String
Dim aLetter As String

temp = StrConv(textt, vbUnicode)
temp = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1)
aLetter = Split(temp, Chr(0))

For i = 1 To Len(textt)
If worksheetfunctions.CountIf(aLetter, Mid(textt, i, 1)) > 1 Then
    textt = textt & "," & Mid(textt, i, 1)
End If
Next i
CountRept = textt & "," & Mid(textt, i, 1)
End Function
```

My intention was to break the string into single characters and then compare it using Mid() and concatenate. Any help and explanation is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function CountRep(str As String) As String
Dim strArr As Variant, repStr As Variant, Dim i As Long
'~~> The For Loop is to evaluate each letter of the word or phrase
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    '~~> First 2 Nested If's is to generate the unique values
    If Not IsArray(strArr) Then
        strArr = Array(Mid$(str, i, 1))
    Else
        If IsError(Application.Match(Mid$(str, i, 1), strArr, 0)) Then
            ReDim Preserve strArr(UBound(strArr) + 1)
            strArr(UBound(strArr)) = Mid$(str, i, 1)
        Else
            '~~> Second Nested If's is to generate the unique repeated values
            If Not IsArray(repStr) Then
                repStr = Array(Mid$(str, i, 1))
            Else
                If IsError(Application.Match(Mid$(str, i, 1), repStr, 0)) Then
                    ReDim Preserve repStr(UBound(repStr) + 1)
                    repStr(UBound(repStr)) = Mid$(str, i, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
'~~> Check if there are repeated values, if none exit
If IsEmpty(repStr) Then CountRep = "-": Exit Function
'~~> Write the output
For i = LBound(repStr) To UBound(repStr)
    If Len(CountRep) = 0 Then
        CountRep = repStr(i)
    Else
        CountRep = CountRep & "," & repStr(i)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Basically, we just used a routine to get unique values twice.
1st is to get the actual unique values and then 2nd is to get the unique repeated values.
We used the built in *Application.Match* function to filter out unique occurrences.
We used *Variant* data type so we could apply built in logical test like *IsArray and IsEmpty*.

Comment: Thank you!! This was spot on, can you please explain this code a little that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are looking for adjacent characters only. The following code will find ALL duplicate letters in a string, adjacent or not. The example string returns "o" or "g,o" if case-insensitive search is used:

```
Function countRep(str as String)

'str = lcase(str)  '--if you want case-insensitive search

Dim msg As String, curr As String
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer

'Make Array as large as the string
Dim letters() As String
ReDim letters(Len(str))

'Loop through letters of string
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    curr = Mid(str, i, 1)
    'Loop through the array for checks
    For k = 1 To i
        'Add letter to message if not already included
        If letters(k) = curr And 0 = InStr(msg, curr) Then msg = msg & curr & ","
    Next k
    'Add letter to array for future checks
    letters(i) = curr
Next i

'Remove trailing comma
countRep = Left(msg, Len(msg) - 1)

End Function
```

If you only want adjacent characters you can skip the use of an array and just save the last letter checked in order to compare it with the following.

Comment: Dear sir, i am looking for a Function, can you adjust it for that secondly being adjacent or not is not an issue, your solution looks similar to what i was trying :) Thank you.  ..

Comment: Sir can u explain the line with Instr()..? Why u used msg here.. thanks alot

Comment: Msg contains one letter for all duplicates I have found. I do not want to re-add a duplicate, i.e. I want every letter to appear only once in the msg. That's why I check if curr is containes in msg (Instr returns the position > 0)